# Javascript element.click() not working with div tags

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason, this simple bit of code isn't ticking the checkbox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Automatically tick the box</p>

<form>
<div id='checkingTheBox'>
    <div class='someValue'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkingTheBox">
    </div>
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

  document.getElementById("checkingTheBox").click();

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

However, when removing the `div` tags, it works fine. Is there any reason why this isn't working as it's shown, and any advice for getting the javascript to click the element successfully without changing HTML structure?

Edit: I tried using `id` instead of `name` inside the `input` tag. That didn't work either.

Comment: When you tried `id` instead of `name`, did you you also remove the now duplicate id from the div?

Comment: What do you expect the `<div>` to do when you click it? If at all you have to "click" the `<input>`

Comment: `// Check
document.getElementById("checkingTheBox").checked = true;

// Uncheck
document.getElementById("checkingTheBox").checked = false;`  add the id to input and when clicked on div inside onclick put this

Comment: With your current HTML: `document.getElementById("checkingTheBox").querySelector('input').click();`

Comment: Got it. A duplicate value for the `id` for both the `input` and `div` is confusing it then. Thanks!

Comment: @n1234 _"so they are searching for other ways of getting help"_ - There's no _"duplicate id"_ in your example

Comment: You can't accept a comment as answer but as a matter of principle I don't post answers to questions that are dupes or can be answered by posting a [link to the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Comment: Instead of a div wrapper, use `label` element, clicking on it toggles the input check state, without needing any JS.

Comment: Was your actual goal to have the checkbox checked from the start? Or was this just about being able to check it from JS? Because if the former, then the `checked` attribute was indeed what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two or more elements on the page with the same `id`. The `id` tag should be unique. Also you cannot use the `name` tag as a `id` tag. It is not the same. Here's the code example which works as you wanted to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Automatically tick the box</p>

<form>
<div>
    <div class='someValue'>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkingTheBox">
    </div>
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

  document.getElementById("checkingTheBox").click();

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
It works but it doesn't make any sense to do that. You can just use a simple `checked` tag in your checkbox to have it to be checked by default. Here's an example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkingTheBox" checked>
```

Comment: _"You cannot have two or more elements on the page with the same id"_ - There are not duplicated ids in OPs question/code.

Comment: That's right, but the name tag in input should be replaced by id tag so I am warning that the id tag in div should be changed or removed in this case.

Answer (score -1):

you are selecting the div and want to click function on it inner child so try this script that will select the inner child from your selected this and call click function on that child

```
const div = document.getElementById('checkingTheBox');
div.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.click();
```